# Windows kernel mode programming: Is a deadlock between drivers possible?

Tags: kernel, driver, deadlock, kmdf, wdf

We're having some issues with our driver hanging while attempting to send a synchronous request to a lower level driver. The routine is currently being executed at `DISPATCH_LEVEL` when this routine is called.

I've been reviewing the Microsoft-supplied document ["Locks, Deadlocks, and Synchronization"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487425) and it says the following:

> Consider the case where code running at a low IRQL successfully acquires a lock, but the thread is interrupted to run code at a higher IRQL. If the higher-IRQL code tries to acquire the same lock, the thread may hang forever. The lower-IRQL code cannot run until the higher-IRQL code exits, but the higher-IRQL code cannot exit until the lower-IRQL code releases the lock. Only a single thread is involved. To prevent this problem, code that acquires a lock usually raises its IRQL to the highest IRQL at which any driver code that acquires the lock can run.

Our problem is giving us hangs and blue screens. While I understand that we aren't supposed to make calls that wait at DISPATCH_LEVEL and that our design needs work, I just want to make sure I understand the IRQL mechanism properly.

Am I correct that the IRQLs are per-processor, and that different drivers are going to run on different processors? I would like to confirm whether or not making a synchronous request targeted at the lower-level driver from `DISPATCH_LEVEL` is actually causing the problem by preempting the thread in the other driver due to its higher IRQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a regular call, the other code will execute on the same CPU at the same level.  If you are doing an async Send, then it may be scheduled on a different CPU.  If you are doing a sync Send from a higher to a lower level driver, then you should probably be hanged.  Just make it async and write the completion routine.

Comment: Great, answered my question! Thanks.